# Duplicate a Database in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, database, database-backups

I have a live database. I need to create a test database with all the data from the live one, but I've encoutneered an error.  I've tried to create this new one by restoring from a "live database .bak", but an error message appears saying that could not do the process because the database is in use. Also, I don't know why but after that, the live database starts restoring and keep on it until getting stuck. It does not finish restoring and I have to force stop, deleting the live database and restoring from scratch. Checking the activity log it seems that it goes to restoring mode after failing to create a backup of the database log and that's what happens right after I try to create the new test database using the .bak.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to duplicate the live database to use it as a test one?

Note: I've done the process when nobody is using the DB or connected to it but no success.

Comment: Impossible to help without the *commands*. There's nothing wrong with backup/restore anyway. All databases are "live". Did you try to restore over the original database perhaps? Did you specify a new name?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What I did was: Right click on database list, restore database, select origin device, select .bak, select destiny, rename the destiny db, change Log path and File path, then go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to relocate/rename the Files.  Just changing the Database name that you are restoring to may not be changing the Database File and Log File that SQL is trying to actually create when you perform the restore.  Go to the Option page of the Restore Database and ensure the files are pointing to Valid locations and not trying to utilize the same files as the Live database.

Comment: The OP should rename the database first. It sounds like he tried to restore over the *original* database

Answer (score 0):

```
--At First take ypur database backup and restore it as DatabaseName_Test and also change Datafiles As database _test.mdf and DatabaseName_test_log.ldf
--try to follow as below script
USE master
GO
BACKUP DATABASE [DatabaseName] 
TO  DISK = N'D:\SQLSERVER_Installation\setup\MSSQL12.SQLSERVER2014\MSSQL\Backup\DatabaseName.bak' 
WITH  COPY_ONLY, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
NAME = N'DatabaseName-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10
GO

USE [master]

RESTORE DATABASE [DatabaseName_Test] FROM  
DISK = N'D:\SQLSERVER_Installation\setup\MSSQL12.SQLSERVER2014\MSSQL\Backup\DatabaseName.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 2,  
MOVE N'DatabaseName' TO N'D:\SQLSERVER_Installation\setup\MSSQL12.SQLSERVER2014\MSSQL\DATA\DatabaseName_test.mdf',  
MOVE N'DatabaseName_log' TO N'D:\SQLSERVER_Installation\setup\MSSQL12.SQLSERVER2014\MSSQL\DATA\DatabaseName_test_log.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

GO
```

Comment: And that helps because? If you want to say that the OP should change the database name instead of restoring over the original database, write it in the answer itself

Comment: @Sreenu131 I did that but using interface, not query. And throw the same message which indicates that it can't restore because database is in use. I don't want to touch it cause worries me the fact that the live db goes restoring again.